# Angular2: replace host element with component's template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm new to `angular` in general and to `angular2` specifically. I'm trying to write a container component, which should have child components in it.

**For example, container component**:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class MyList {
}
```

**Child component:**

```typescript
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  template: `
    <li>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </li>
  `
})
export class MyItem {
}
```

I'd like to make this structure:

```html
<my-list>
    <my-item>One</my-item>
    <my-item>Two</my-item>
</my-list>
```

To be rendered to the following one:

```html
<my-list>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</my-list>
```

But instead, I have the host element of the container and the items preserved as well:

```html
<my-list>
    <ul>
        <my-item>
            <li>One</li>
        </my-item>
        <my-item>
            <li>Two</li>
        </my-item>
    </ul>
 </my-list>
```

[Plunk is available here](https://plnkr.co/edit/um5BC7?p=preview)

**Question:** is there a way to eliminate the host elements and to leave only the rendered template?

Comment: see https://plnkr.co/edit/7nMTnH?p=preview

Comment: @EricMartinez, in your plunk I see that you replaced the usage of `my-list` and `my-item` by direct usage of `ul` and `li`. This is pointless. I meant `my-list` and `my-item` to be the components, which render themselves to `ul` and `li` accordingly. Of course, this is just a very simplified example. The real case is much more complex, but the main point is still the same: to eliminate (replace) host elements

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found solution: injecting `ElementRef` to `MyItem` and using its `nativeElement.innerHTML`:

**MyList**:

```typescript
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from 'angular2/core'
import { MyItem } from './myitem'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#item of items" [innerHTML]="item.innerHTML"></li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class MyList {
  @ContentChildren(MyItem) items: QueryList<MyItem>
}
```

**MyItem:**

```typescript
import { Directive, Inject, ElementRef } from 'angular2/core'

@Directive({selector: 'my-item'})
export class MyItem {
  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) element: ElementRef) {
    this.innerHTML = element.nativeElement.innerHTML
  }
}
```

[Working plunk is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/um5BC7?p=preview)

Comment: @Natanael, you can find a working plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/um5BC7?p=preview

Comment: @Natanael you have to access innerHTML inside ngAfterContentInit callback. It is empty if you access it inside constructor. I edited answer to reflect this...

Comment: Fair warning: Do not use InnerHTML for anything other than **static** HTML. This includes bindings, other components, whatever - it will mess things up

Answer (score 24):

This you should get what you want:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'ul[my-list]',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class MyList {
}
```

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'li[my-item]',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class MyItem {
...
}
```

```html
<ul my-list>
    <li my-item>One</li my-item>
    <li my-item>Two</li my-item>
</ul my-list>
```

Comment: This will work, but it's not exactly what I need. This causes the user of my component to be aware of my implementation DOM structure (ul/li) - making me much less flexible to change this structure in future (e.g. to divs)

Comment: What you can do is to not use `ul` and `li` but `my-item` with CSS `my-item: { display: list-item;}`, then it behaves like a list item but doesn't have to be one and you can use the element selectors you had in your question (but with the template content of my answer)

Comment: With CSS there might be another problem: I would like to use existing `bootstrap` CSS and to be able to update it smoothly. Is there a way to reuse `bootstrap`'s styles for `ul` and `li` and to apply them on custom elements?

Comment: Sure, but only when they are actually `<ul>` and `<li>` elements like in my answer not when used like in your question or my previous comment.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Is there an alternative to this solution?  I tried copying in the code that you supplied and it does not work.  Thanks.

Comment: It throws this error The selector should be kebab-cased and include a dash (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-02) (component-selector)tslint(1)

Comment: That's just a style rule that you can decide to follow, ignore, or comply with.

Comment: Does this work in 2022 ? I tried it & got an error & the Angular interpreter did not expect the `my-item` of the closing tag.

Answer (score 4):

New angular versions have really cool directive, which may be used also for your use case. Tadaa: [NgComponentOutlet](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet). Happy coding ;)

Example:

```
@Component({selector: 'hello-world', template: 'Hello World!'})
class HelloWorld {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-component-outlet-simple-example',
  template: `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="HelloWorld"></ng-container>`
})
class NgTemplateOutletSimpleExample {
  // This field is necessary to expose HelloWorld to the template.
  HelloWorld = HelloWorld;
}
```

Comment: And also interesting variation [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).. this one did the thing for me :)

Comment: Please provide a usage example

Comment: @StevenLiekens example was in docs, but I have copied it here.. ng-container element is used, which is meta element replaced during compilation.

Comment: I mean can you show how to solve the asker's problem using NgComponentOutlet?

Answer (score -3):

In the latest angular you can even avoid adding `<ng-content></ng-content>`

I've applied is like:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'div[app-root]',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Delegates Presence Reporting';
}
```

and the template:

```
<div class="centered">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<body>
<div app-root></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing gets replaced. The output will be a div class="centered" inside the div app-root.